# TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this line in my code at website

http://talentbridge.pl/webinar/landingRB.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#timeleft").countdown("2016/05/06");});
```

and it is giving me this error:

> TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function
>       $("#timeleft").countdown("2016/05/06");

Please let me know how to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: see the docs to fix the function http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Comment: If you want to use it as a jQuery-Plugin change to src to e.g. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.1.0/jquery.countdown.min.js` and have a look at the link above.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the source from [countdownjs.org](https://github.com/mckamey/countdownjs), but nowhere there it is stated that this is a jQuery-plugin which can be used with `$().countdown()`. See their [demo](https://github.com/mckamey/countdownjs/blob/master/demo.js)-page for an example of the usage.

Furthermore I would recommend not to use a github-url as a CDN for your javascript sources.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming $ here refers to jQuery . jQuery doesn't have anything called `countdown` . Probably someone in your team defined a prototype function , by extending jquery
Like as shown:

`$.prototype.countdown = function(){alert(1)};
$('head'). countdown();`

You need to re-define it , or check the commit list .